# Porting only HTTP portion of libcurl

Tags: curl

I am evaluating libcurl in order to extract only HTTP functionality for a custom OS without rest of the protocols like ftp, rtsp etc. On the face of it, it looks like a big effort. Has anyone done a libcurl port with only HTTP?

Comment: Is the custom OS POSIX based?

Answer (score 0):

When building libcurl you can specifically disable all the protocols you don't need/like. This work has already been done!